# Nodejs + Mongodb tailable cursor stream() query keeps running in background

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use this code to get the latest data from mongodb collection
https://gist.github.com/jpaljasma/3260eaa6f7a40315863d#file-tailable-cursor-js

the issue is when

```
// create stream and listen 
var stream = coll.find(filter, cursorOptions).sort({$natural: -1}).stream();
```

the above line is executed.. a query starts which I can seen in mongod console

so far I am able to pause this query using stream.pause(); only when any data is being received.

also the data event

```
// call the callback
stream.on('data', next);
```

is called only when any data is inserted in db

I want to find a way so I can get even the null results of the query which is constantly running in background.

the issue is as soon as the page is loaded I execute this code and the stream query starts in background which I am using it for a live graph and it's fine as long as the browser is open but I want it to stop as soon as the browser gets closed.

Comment: adding a check if socket is disconnected and strean is still readable and then inserting a doc and using stream.pause works but this is just too much and I end up with extra unnecessary data in my capped collection

Comment: ok after little more work, this is confirmed that pause does work but only when any new record is added in collection, so for example if page got refreshed 4 times and I paused the stream 4 times then all the 4 stream getmore will keep running in background until any record is added in collection